# How do I properly use a Keras Add layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to merge two LSTM layers together, to no success.

```
answers_questions_lstm = LSTM(256,input_shape=(8,4,))
answers_contexts_lstm = LSTM(256,input_shape=(10,6,))
answers_combined_lstm = Add()([answers_questions_lstm,answers_contexts_lstm])
answers_hidden_1 = Dense(124)(answers_combined_lstm)
answers_output = Dense(outputTrain.shape[1])
answers_network_1.summary()
```

This gives me "A merge layer should be called on a list of inputs." Why?

Comment: You did not give inputs to your LSTM, so you are passing a list of layers, when you need a list of layer outputs

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using the [Keras Functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/), you should start with some [Input](https://keras.io/layers/core/#input) layers. Then call your LSTM layers on the Inputs to get tensor outputs that can then be passed to the Add layer:

```
answers_questions_input = Input(shape=(8,4))
answers_contexts_input = Input(shape=(10,6))
answers_questions_lstm = LSTM(256)(answers_questions_input)
answers_contexts_lstm = LSTM(256)(answers_contexts_input)
answers_combined_lstm = Add()([answers_questions_lstm, answers_contexts_lstm])
answers_hidden_1 = Dense(124)(answers_combined_lstm)
answers_output = Dense(outputTrain.shape[1])
answers_network_1 = Model(inputs=[answers_questions_input, answers_contexts_input], outputs=answers_output)
answers_network_1.summary()
```